# How do you get window[VariableName] into an if statement condition?

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables

I have managed to join a parameter and a string together to make a variable name using the `window[]` function.

```
function myFunc(playerNumber){
    window[playerNumber + "total"] += temporaryVariableStorage;
    update(playernumber);
}
```

The `myFunc()` function works perfectly so this bit ... `window[playerNumber + "total"]` ... does evaluate to the correct variable name but as soon as I put the exact same line into an if statement, it doesn't work???

```
function update(playerNumber){
    if((window[playerNumber + "total"]) > 21){
        alert("Hi there");
    }
}
```

I have tried removing the brackets, converting it to a string using `.toString` and `String()` nothing I do seems to work?

Please help, thank you!

Comment: I have also tried assigning a new variable called `b` for example, this here `window[playerNumber + "total"]` and then passing the variable name into the if statement so that it looks like this... `if(b > 21){
        alert("Hi there");
    }` but it didn't work either!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `myFunc` function, you've put `update(playernumber)` instead of `update(playerNumber)`

Your problem was not capitalising the 'n' in 'Number'.

Comment: I don't believe it! It was that simple! Unbelievable! Thank you very much!

Comment: @PleaseHelp no problem. Glad it helped :-) it's always something as simple as that

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? @Mark Eriksson

Comment: Go for it @PleaseHelp

Comment: How would I use the same line in disabling a button. So why does this not work? `document.getElementById(("p" + playerNumber + "button").toString).disabled = true;`

Comment: I am trying to get into a string like in this working example `document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;`

Comment: @PleaseHelp are you trying this within your myFunc function?

Comment: I added it under the `alert()` line in the `update()` function

Comment: You shouldn't need the `toString` part. `document.getElementById('p' + playerNumber + 'button').disabled=true;` should suffice

Comment: OMG YOR ARE A GENIUS, I HOPE TO BE AS SMART AS YOU ONE DAY!

Comment: BUT HOW DOES THAT WORK, I THOUGH IT NEEDED TO BE IN STRING FORM

Comment: I SUPPOSE BECAUSE IT IS BEING ADDED TO STRING NOT NUMBERS IT AUTOMATICALLY JUST MAKES IT A STRING BUT NORMALLY JAVASCRIPT ISN'T THAT NICE

Comment: i JUST ACCEPTED YOUR ANSWER! :)

Comment: @PleaseHelp it already is a string :-)  you're surrounding it in quotes and even starting it in quotes, so it automatically becomes a string. If you had a line of code such as `var x = 23;`, x would be an integer. If you wanted to make it a string, you could do `var y = x.toString();` or even just `var y = '' + x;`. `y` would then be a string.

Comment: @PleaseHelp that's exactly why (in reply to your 'I suppose because it is being added...' Message)

Comment: I am having another issue of similar nature to this one